# How to get the directory path in groovy

Tags: groovy

I want to store file in my_application/PdfReports directory ,i am writing the code to store in the file which is in  my_application/grails-app/domain/com/my_company/my_application/reports/ReportExporter.groovy .

So how to get the path my_application/PdfReportsv to store files.

Comment: is there any way to get the path mentioned above in groovy file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying the web-app as a `war`, then I'm not sure the path `my_application/PdfReports` makes any sense.

The war file (and exploded war folder) will be the contents of your `web-app` folder, with related grails stuff inside the `WEB-INF` folder

Why not use a custom absolute path which you can define in your `Config.groovy` file

Or, to get the real disk based path for your web-application, you could do something like:

```
 String webAppPath = new File( servletContext.getRealPath( '/index.gsp' ) ).parentFile.absolutePath
```

from inside a controller